# Javascript check if parameter contain this keyword

Tags: javascript

i have a problem for checking javascript function containing **this** keyword or not.

so, this is my code :

```
function check(el) {        
    if (el === this) {

        return el;
    }
    else {
        alert("not contain this keyword");
    }
}
check(this);
```

it's always showing `alert()`

i try `el` **==** `this`,
i try `el` **=** `this`

both are still not working.

is it possible to use **typeof** checking?

what's wrong with my code?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? The way you are calling `check`, it will have a `this` of the window object, and you are passing `this` as a parameter which is also the window object, so of course they're equal. `el = this` will assign `this` to the `el` object, and evaluate to the result, which is truthy so again the `if` condition will be satisfied.

Comment: Both outcomes have an alert, so your question is quite unclear. When using `==` and `===` you're comparing `this` to `this`. When using `=` you're assigning. Regardless, its' not clear what you're trying to do. You mention containing, but what is supposed to *contain* what?

Comment: i edited my question, sorry for misunderstanding. i'm building my own DOM function. not dependent to jquery

Comment: As I understood you try to do `check('this')` and `if (el.indexOf('this') !== -1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to match the string(wrap the text inside single/double quote). Use the below code.

```
function check(el) {

    if (el === 'this') {
        alert("contain!");
        return el;
    } else {
        alert("not contain this keyword");
    }
}

check('this');
```

Comment: i forget to say that this is a keyword, not a string. btw, thanks Santhosh

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to match the text "this", wrap single or double quotes around this. The below code alerts if passed string contains "this"

```
function check(e1) {
    if (e1.indexOf("this") > -1) {
        alert("contain!");
        return e1;
    } else {
        alert("not contain this keyword");
    }
}
check("this");
```

The below code checks if passed word is just "this"

```
function check(el) {
    if (el === "this") {
        alert("contain!");
        return el;
    } else {
        alert("not contain this keyword");
    }
}
check("this");
```

Comment: It seems unlikely that this is what the OP is trying to do, whatever that might be. Better to leave a comment asking if he is trying to find the substring `"this"` inside the `el` parameter. BTW, your code formatting is a bit off.

Comment: this is a keyword, not a string. thanks Nithin